# How to write a Jax-Rs handler to authenticate the Requests

Tags: oauth, request, jax-rs, handler

I want to write a Jax-Rs handler which should get all the REST calls given from a REST client and validate the OAuth access token and forward the http request to the respective resource classes.

I meant to say that, Jax-Rs handler will be the central place to handle all the request by validating the value passed by Authorization header.

I am expecting an urgent reply.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how it's done in [rexsl-page](http://www.rexsl.com/rexsl-page/inset-oauth.html). Take a look at two classes, one for [Google OAuth](http://trac.rexsl.com/rexsl/browser/rexsl/trunk/rexsl-page/src/main/java/com/rexsl/page/auth/Google.java) and another one for [Facebook OAuth](http://trac.rexsl.com/rexsl/browser/rexsl/trunk/rexsl-page/src/main/java/com/rexsl/page/auth/Facebook.java). You can also use the entire framework, or just copy given classes.

In a nutshell, you create a common parent class for all your JAX-RS resources. In this class you parse incoming `HttpHeaders` and tries to find a cookie with an encrypted authentication token (user identity). If found, you do nothing. If not found, you throw a `WebApplicationException` that redirects the user to the "please login" page.

Comment: Yegor, Thanks for your reply. My usecase is different. I already have done the REST API with OAuth secured. The current rest api is cxf web app. the problem with current model is that when I give a call from rest client it goes to resource class then validate the access token on its super class. all the resources classes are extending the super class which has the access token validation logic. I plan to move the validation logic to jax-rs handler to avoid the super class, once validation is success, pass the calls to respective resource classes. my resource class are annotated with beans.

Comment: JAX-RS handlers is a good option, but they are not standardized yet: http://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/pages/InterceptorsAndFilters